# CSS styled div doesn´t start from the window side (VB express)

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2013, styling

I am creating a site in VB Express 2013. I need that black div to start right from the side of the screen. I don´t understand what is in the waym you can clearly see there is a little white space. I used vw and vh units.
You can see the code and css on the picture. 
Thank you.

[image: Mozilla Firefox]

Edit:
Ok doesnt show the code very well. Here is HTML code:

```
<head></head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" action="Login.aspx" method="post">
        <div class="aspNetHidden"></div>
        <div>
            <div id="div_LoginArea" class="LoginArea">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="aspNetHidden"></div>
    </form>
    <script id="__browserLink_initializationData" type="application/json"></script>
    <script async="async" src="http://localhost:52998/fdd2cbbabb234e7aaf368c863afd77b0/browserLink" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--

     End Browser Link 

    -->
</body>
```

Here is CSS of that div:

```
div.LoginArea{
position:relative;
margin-top:10vh;
background-color:black;
height:80vh;
width:100vw;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For body tag there is default margin is set as 8px by browser. Reset to 0px.

```
body{
margin:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your div is inside another div , another div, form and budy tag, check if any of those have a margin or a padding on the left side